# Parallel bulk loading using partition switching of indexed table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, indexing, bulkinsert, data-warehouse, data-partitioning

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933163/bulk-inserts-of-heavily-indexed-child-items-sql-server-2008) of mine after definitely deciding on partition switching as the best way to quickly get data into a heavily indexed fact type table that needs to remain available to readers.

While it seems to be the best way, it is not quite good enough to really satisfy the requirement to allow several (< 5) users to bulk insert at the same time, have the new data indexed and to appear in the indexed views (not necessarily real indexed views, just selects that rely on indices).

The idea of partitioning was that each partition and the index subtree rooted at the partition could, in parallel, be locked as read-only, copied into a working table, new data inserted/updated and the indexes rebuilt then switched back into the main table so readers aren't affected.

The problem is the single working table. Each parallel bulk insert needs its own copy, with the same constraints as the main table to allow switching.

So far I've hit several walls trying to get around this bottleneck:

1. I tried partitioning the working table using the same partition
   function. This doesn't work because you can't disable the indexes on
   a partition basis to insert into one while rebuilding the index on
   another.
2. Creating a temporary table as the working table. This
   doesn't work because, while you can use the same index names, you
   can't easily dynamically create the constraints and can't switch
   that in anyway.
3. Have a fixed set of named working tables? How can I select one and work with it under an alias so I have just one stored proc?
4. Dynamic SQL? I've tried very hard to avoid going that route. It's complicated as it is.

Big challenge but has anyone got any ideas before I accept the bottleneck? Would Sql 2012 help? How do proper data warehouses cope with this?

Answer (score 3):

How do proper data warehouses cope with this? Compromise and set realistic goals for the EDW. The data warehouse can't be everything to everyone. Make sure that what you're implementing is the best solution for the business (not just the techies/analysts). Are your goals realistic if you cannot find solutions from experienced peers and experts?

Associate a cost with all of the hoops you jump through. Does the data really need to be up to the minute? What if I told you that we needed to spend another $200,000 on storage because we're constantly duplicating partitions and rebuilding indexes and the current solution can't keep up with the IOPS demand? At some point, they're going to figure out that it's not free. While you don't need to just say no, you do need to be realistic and up-front about the cost associated. Additionally, your storage admin will thank you.

As for 2012, there is a new columnstore index which can reduce or replace all of the current nonclustereds you're using to cover all you're analysts search requests. It's highly compressed, covers a very wide variety of search arguments, and utilizes the new Batch execution mode. It performs best on low selectivity queries like the ones frequently performed on fact tables. The one catch is that you can't directly do updates. You'll have to switch the partition out to a staging table, drop the columnstore on the staging table, update the staging table, add the columnstore back, then switch the partition back into the fact table. It sounds like alot, but could be significantly faster and require less IO than maintaining all of those nonclustereds.

My question has always been "Is it really a fact table if it is constantly changing?". This is not OLTP is it? Try offsetting transactions or at least push all updates to a scheduled off-peak time. Updating fact tables is becoming a thing of the past. All of the [big boys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) are moving toward the "Update frowned upon" column oriented architecture for data warehousing. PowerPivot and the Analysis Services Tabular Model are built on the columnstore technology.

Finally, Review Kimballs' DW Toolkit books. He has several that lay out best practices and cover edge-case scenarios. What I learned from them was that Data Warehouse Development is not just Database Development on steroids. It also involves politics and focusing resources on what's best for the business.